# What is the standard programming font used in Textmate?

Tags: fonts, textmate

It looks very readable. I specifically like how the text is a little bit bolder than Consolas, sort of like Comic Sans.

Is it downloadable for windows?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Monaco.

It is downloadable for Windows [here](http://www.webdevkungfu.com/textmate-envy-aka-monaco-font-for-windows/)
(Direct link: http://www.webdevkungfu.com/files/MONACO.TTF)

Answer (score 3):

I believe it's Monaco 12 pt.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to use the same font on Linux, you can by following the instructions on this blog: http://jorrel.blogspot.com/2007/11/monaco-on-ubuntu.html

Answer (score 1):

This isn't exactly an answer, but you might also want to check out [Anonymous Pro](http://www.ms-studio.com/FontSales/anonymouspro.html). I've tried a lot of programming fonts over the years, and I have never found another one nearly as readable. (I know the link path says "font sales", but the font is free and licensed under the SIL Open Font License.)

Answer (score 1):

TextMate 2 default font is **Menlo** 12pt.

*View > Font > Show Fonts*

[How to download it for Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/59456/any-good-way-to-get-the-new-menlo-font-on-windows)

Answer (score 0):

I use "DejaVuSansMono" and my eyes are very comfortable with it. It's more like the standard font that "textmate" in Mac. Very nice. I recommend it to everybody.